# UITapGestureRecognizer Stops touchesEnded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make an iPhone app that is controlled by touch. I also want a powerup to be activated when the user double-taps. Here's what I have so far:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *powerRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(usePower)];
powerRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
powerRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
powerRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:powerRecognizer];
[powerRecognizer release];
```

But the problem is, when I double-tap, my `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method only fires once, but my `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method fires twice. Since `touchesBegan:` sets a timer and `touchesEnded:` invalidates it, then when `touchesEnded:` only fires once, the timer is still running. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using touches began/ended when you have a gesture recognizer set-up for the method usePower?

Comment: I think Jake wants to be able to do more than double tap. Drag the view around the screen using a touch, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution for detecting double-taps:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{   

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if([touch tapCount] == 2) {
// do sth   
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift, you can avoid the standard behaviour and let the UITouch event propagate to view and its child, even if a gesture is recognized, with

```
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Both `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a gesture recognizer to a view changes the behavior of several touch handling methods, including [`touchesEnded:WithEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW17).

From the above link:

> After observation, the delivery of
>   touch objects to the attached view, or
>   their disposition otherwise, is
>   affected by the cancelsTouchesInView,
>   delaysTouchesBegan, and
>   delaysTouchesEnded properties.