# touchesEnded method doesn't get called?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, iphone-4, iphone-3gs

I am developing an application in which I use

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
}

-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
}
```

Now my problem in iphone 3 after `touch move` it is calling `handleSingleTap` function and `touchesEnded` didn't get called. This happen only on some lower part of the screen when I move there touch end didn't get called.If I move long then `touchesEnded` get called.

But this thing is working properly in IPhone4 and IPad.
In IPhone4 and IPad after `touchsesMoved` it is calling `touchesEnded`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITapGestureRecognizer Stops touchesEnded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851637/uitapgesturerecognizer-stops-touchesended)

Comment: @beryllium i dint get why you saying this possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not the only one who has encountered this problem. I found a similar thread on Apple Support forum list : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1507669?start=0&tstart=0

This thread dates from 2008 which coincides with the iPhone 3, so I guess there might be a chance this is an unfixed bug on iOS running on iPhone 3.

Otherwise if it's not the case, may be it's due to the fact that you are using a UIScrollView (whose controller is implementing the touch methods you listed above). By default, it has a method called :

```
delaysContentTouches
```

That is set to YES. May be you should change it to no and say how it behaves.

If you are not using a UIScrollView, may be you are using two view and the second view containing the "dead area" is not connected to your controller ?